# Discord OAuth2 how to check if a bot is in (joined) a guild

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

I'm using Discord OAuth2 for my discord bot dashboard. I retrieve the user's servers by the link https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds. I want to prompt the user to add my bot to his guild or go directly to the dashboard if the bot is already in the user's guild. But how do I know if the bot is already in a guild? I didn't find any API that does this.

Comment: Are you using a library such as discord.js or discord.py?

Comment: No I'm not. I'm using the http(s) api.

Answer (score 2):

It's an API request per guild, but you could use [get guild member](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member) with your own bot's ID; if you get a 4xx then your bot isn't present in the guild.